# Installing Github .zip files on Chromebook via Linux

Tags: bash, github, installation, chromebook

I'm using a Linux Debian terminal, trying to install a Github .zip file by following a walkthrough (from Chromebook). They're using a Windows terminal and access the zip file from a G: drive. They run the following:

```
C:\Users\zasur>G:

G:\>cd filename.zip

G:\filename>npm install
```

Which installs the Github zip. I've looked all over online and tried a few different solutions but can't get past the second command they run.

I was able to open `/mnt/chromeos/MyFiles/Downloads` from Linux by sharing the Downloads folder with it.

I'm not sure how to change the directory from here to the `filename.zip` and/or run commands from it. Whenever I try to run `cd filename.zip` or `cd /mnt/chromeos/MyFiles/Downloads/filename.zip` it always fails. Is this even possible on a Chromebook?

Comment: There are a couple of problems here. You can't `cd` to a zip file, because it's not a directory. And `npm install` is for installing dependencies in a Node project, or for installing a global npm package, not for installing general programs (and you can `npm i` from a repo link, depending on what you're trying to do).

Comment: Please give me a link to that tutorial.

Comment: Here's the walkthrough https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qSu1XhV0848 and here's the original Github link https://github.com/GreySole/Spooder